# Nonhomogeneous ODE by power series ($y'' + 4y' + 6y = 1 + e^{(-t)}$)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, taylor-expansion, power-series

I'm trying to solve this ODE using power series around zero

$y'' + 4y' + 6y = 1 + e^{(-t)}$

with $y(0) = 1$ and $y'(0) = 0$

Once I replaced $y(t), y'(t)$, $y''(t)$ and $1 + e^{(-t)}$, respectively,  with

$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_{n-2} t^{n-2}$, $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_{n-1} (n-1)t^{n-2}$,
$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_{n} n(n-1)t^{n-2} $ and  $1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n} \dfrac{t^{n}}{n!} $

the following equalitys comes:

$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}t^{n-2}(a_nn(n-1) + 4(n-1)a_{n-1} + 6a_{n-2}) =  1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n} \dfrac{t^{n}}{n!}$

So

$2a_2 + 4a_1 + 6a_0 = 2$

$6a_3 + 8a_2 + 6a_1 = -1$

$12a_4 + 12a_3 + 6a_2 = \dfrac{1}{2!}$

I couldn't find the pattern for the even and odd terms

Comment: You made a mistake: $e^{-t}=\Sigma \dfrac{(-t)^n}{n!}$

Comment: Thanks @tomi. I wrote right in my notes buth wrong in the post. :)

Can't find the pattern yet.

Comment: Are you truly obligated to use power series? For this example there is at least one less-computational approach...

Comment: Yes. I already solved using Laplace and undetermined coefficients approaches

Comment: Should have $6a_3 + 8a_2 + 6a_1 = 0$ and $12a_4 + 12a_3 + 6a_2 = 2$

Comment: @gmn_1450 You pointed out that you solved it using Laplace Transform and undeterminated coefficients, so you know the particular solution is given by $y(t)=\displaystyle Ae^{-2t}\sin(\sqrt{2}t)+Be^{-2t}\cos(\sqrt{2}t)+\frac{e^{-t}}{3}+\frac{1}{3!}$ with $A=\frac{1}{2}(2y(0)-1)$ and $B=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{6}(-2+6y(0)+3y'(0))$. Then why are you looking for the solution using series?

Comment: Also, you mention that you do not find a pattern, that is clearly due to the terms $e^{-2t}\sin(\sqrt{2}t)$ and $e^{-2t}\cos(\sqrt{2}t)$ in the solution, think in the series expansion to $e^{-2t}$ and $\cos \sqrt{2}t$ and $\sin \sqrt{2}t$ an then the product and then the $n-$term. If you still wish to continue along this series way, I recommend that you solve the homogeneous case first: $y''+4y'+6y=0$ using series and then considere find the particular solution. If you consider the whole problem, you first have to fix term $1$ which is left alone in your stated series equation.

Comment: @user1027216 the sequence of the homogeneous ODE has zero solutions $a_n = \dfrac{4a_{n-1}(1-n) - a_{n-2}}{n(n-1)}, a_ 0= 1, a_1 = 0$